# Error instantiating servlet class - HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, servlets

Trying to create a new servlet .... but getting error

HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class

1. My servlet class looks like

   ```
   package com.example.tutorial;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   @WebServlet(description = "Test servlet this is", urlPatterns = { "/servletexample" })
   public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public ServletExample() {
       super();
   }

   protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
           HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       out.println("Testing servlet !!!");
   }

   }
   ```
2. My web.xml looks like :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
     <display-name>ServletJSPExample</display-name>
     <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>

     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.example.tutorial.ServletExample</servlet-class>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/servletexample</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

   </web-app>
   ```

Don't know what is happening...... Would appreciate help .....

Comment: If 500 the exception is expected. Please show stacktrace

Comment: @WebServlet annotation is enough. You don't need to configure the Servlet tags for it again in web.xml.

Comment: In Servlet 3.0 several new annotations are introduced which are part of package javax.servlet.annotation.They are intended to provide meta data only.In JSR 315, one can specify the servlet meta data by using @ WebServlet. So when u are using annotation like @ WebServlet u no more need any deployment descriptor (web.xml). So either use @ WebServlet annotation without web.xml or remove the annotation and use web.xml. Do not use both.

Comment: The answer is in the exception and stack trace. Read server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either remove your annotation or the web.xml mapping.

if you need both approaches, it should be similar to below:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ServletExample", urlPatterns = {"/servletExample"})
public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
....
}
```

and the mapping in web.xml should be:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.tutorial.ServletExample</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletExample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It looks to me that you're missing the "**name**" attribute in your @WebServlet annotation. put it and try again.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the help. I removed servlet description from web.xml and it works fine.

Comment: glad it helps... so why don't you accept it as the answer and help the community who got the same issue?